# Jqgrid: getRowData fails with error unable to get property name of undefined

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to call this method on a grouped jqgrid. My call to getGridParam does work but it fails on getRowData.

```
var selRow = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
myGrid.getRowData(selRow);
```

Comment: The code is removed from any context. Is any row selected at the moment of execution the code (is `selRow !== null`)? Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: Yes the selRow does have an integer value. I use jqgrid 4.3.1, paid.

Comment: `selRow` doesn't have to hold an integer value. It should be the row id (the value of `id` of `<tr>` element). jqGrid 4.3.1 is available for free and it can't be paid. On the other side jqGrid 4.3.1 is 6 years old, which is an eternity for the web development. It's better if you provide the demo (in jsFiddle for example), which reproduce the problem, or at least post more JavaScript code.